# How to remove email addresses from a list in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure, there is a report which is being sent on a daily basis to around 25 recipients. I want to remove one of the email id from that list.

Suppose I want to remove `abc@test.com`, what should I do?

3 email addresses: `abc@test.com; 123@test.com; 456@test.com`

Here is the code which I am trying:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE [BCCDW].[Config].[StoredProcExecution] 
SET Recipients = '123@test.com;456@test.com'
WHERE SPName = 'p_rpt_daily_alarm'

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the stored procedure itself?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: So what are you asking? Does your update not work?

Comment: Also, it is generally a really bad idea to have multiple items of information concatenated together in a single column. In any relational database, if you want to store "multiple of something" - you should create a separate table and each row would be one of those somethings....

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution. It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Recipients VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Recipients) VALUES
('abc@test.com; 123@test.com; 456@test.com');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @emailRemove VARCHAR(100) = 'abc@test.com';

UPDATE @tbl
SET Recipients = TRIM(' ;' FROM REPLACE(Recipients, @emailRemove, ''));

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Before**

```
+----+------------------------------------------+
| ID |                Recipients                |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | abc@test.com; 123@test.com; 456@test.com |
+----+------------------------------------------+
```

**After**

```
+----+----------------------------+
| ID |         Recipients         |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 123@test.com; 456@test.com |
+----+----------------------------+
```